# Gradle 3.0 pulling jars from Gitlab registry?

Tags: gradle, gitlab, build.gradle

Lets say I have a gitlab registry in my corporate network which has the following url:

```
https://gitlab.corp.xyz.com/api/v4/projects/1234/packages/maven
```

To connect to it, a private token is needed. Lets say my account has the following token

```
Name: Private-Token
Value: rVV8qr58zrkO5CV37HYf4
```

I have an application using gradle. In order to pull the needed jar files from that repository, to be used in my application....In my **build.gradle** file repositories section, I attempted the following:

```
repositories {
   maven {
      url "https://gitlab.corp.xyz.com/api/v4/projects/1234/packages/maven"
      authentication {
        basic(BasicAuthentication)
        withHeaders {
            header('Private-Token', 'rVV8qr58zrkO5CV37HYf4')
        }
      }
   }
}
```

But I get the following error upon build:

```
Cannot create a Authentication named 'withHeaders' because this container does not support creating elements by name alone. Please specify which subtype of Authentication to create. Known subtypes are: BasicAuthentication, DigestAuthentication
```

I tried another way, as recommended in [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html) but it didnt work either.

```
repositories {
maven {
    url "https://gitlab.corp.xyz.com/api/v4/projects/1234/packages/maven"
    credentials(HttpHeaderCredentials) {
        name = "Private-Token"
        value = "rVV8qr58zrkO5CV37HYf4"
    }
    authentication {
        header(HttpHeaderAuthentication)
    }
}
```

}

I am using an old version. **Gradle 3.0**.

Can anyone help me on this? so I could download my needed jars from that particular gitlab repository